# Replace order dates in XML file via python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am looking to write a simple python program that will read an XML file with order dates, and read a csv file with updated order dates and then if the order date has changed for an order it will update the xml file and save it.

for example in the XML file it reads;

```
    <ppr:Order ppr:id="1|19048694">
    <ppr:number>M907003465</ppr:number>
    <ppr:startTime>**2019-10-28T06:45:00**</ppr:startTime>
```

and the CSV has

```
    Order        Date
    M907003465   **2020-03-16T08:00:02**
```

So the program would update the XML file and save it so that it now reads

```
   <ppr:Order ppr:id="1|19048694">
    <ppr:number>M907003465</ppr:number>
    <ppr:startTime>**2020-03-16T08:00:02**</ppr:startTime>
```

[XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCSXr.png)
[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Pwu.png)

Comment: *I am looking to write a simple python program* ... StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please do the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451), make an earnest attempt at coding and debugging, and come back with specific issues/errors that you cannot resolve with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this together, to update the xml file with the correct order times from the csv file. It essentially takes the XML and CSV file and makes 4 lists,

xml order numbers
xml times
csv order numbers
csv times

It compares the lists and if the order number matches on the xml file and the csv it replaces the xml time with the time from the csv file.

and finally it replaces the .text of the children tags (original order times) with the values of the xml time list

```
#import csv model
import csv
#Import xml model
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#Get order numbers and times from CSV file
with open('Copy of AMS Schedule.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    order_numbers = []
    csvtimes = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        csvtimes.append(line['Date'])
        order_numbers.append(line['Order'])

#XML file path down to order numbers and times
mytree = ET.parse('OL.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()
orderlist = myroot[1]
productionprogram = orderlist[0]

#Take xml order numbers and put them into a list
xmlordernumbers = [x.text for x in productionprogram.iter('{http://ManHub.PPRData}number')]
#print(xmlordernumbers)

#Take xml order times and put them into a list
xmltimes = [x.text for x in productionprogram.iter('{http://ManHub.PPRData}startTime')]
#print(xmltimes)

#Take all lists, compare and update xmltimes
trans = {k: v for k, v in zip(order_numbers, csvtimes)}
xmltimes = [trans.get(k, item) for k, item in zip(xmlordernumbers, xmltimes)]
#print(xmltimes)

#put values from list of updated XML times back into XML children
for idx, day in enumerate(productionprogram.iter('{http://ManHub.PPRData}startTime')):
    day.text = xmltimes[idx]

#validate that the values from the xml children contain new times
updatedxmltimes = [x.text for x in productionprogram.iter('{http://ManHub.PPRData}startTime')]
#print(updatedxmltimes)

#write new xml file
mytree.write('output.xml')
```